# Disabling Computer Object on Creation in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to create a computer object and immediately disable it. Right now this second I do that with something that looks like...

```
$x = New-ADComputer -Name ... -Path ... -SAMAccountName ... -Description ... | Disable-ADAccount
```

That's fine and it works.

I'd love to disble the account on creation through the -OtherAttributes parameter:

```
$x = New-ADComputer -Name ... -Path ... -SAMAccountName ... -Description ...  -OtherAttributes { 'Enabled' = 'False' }
```

But, I can't get that working as I get:

> "...specified directory service attribute or value does not exist".

I want to accept that `Enabled` isn't valid, or I can't set it here. I feel like AD is lying. I feel like I can. It's in Microsoft's stupid list of [Active Directory All Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx)

So, before I rollover and just go with the snippet that I know works, I wanted to ask if the `OtherAttributes` way COULD work? Assuming I'm just screwing it up some how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-Enabled` parameter when calling `New-ADComputer`:

```
$x = New-ADComputer -Name ... -Path ... -SAMAccountName ... -Description ... -Enabled:$false
```